# SpriteKit: Remove Nodes in Region

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create my first iOS app by using SpriteKit. Is there a way to remove all nodes in a certain region of the scene without iterating over every point in the region? I cannot think of a better way to do so besides:

```
for a in 0..<width {
    for b in 0..<height {
        let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(CGPoint(x: x + a, y: y + b))
        self.removeChildrenInArray(nodes)
    }
}
```

where the region I want to remove nodes from is at the point ("x", "y") with the width of "width" and height of "height". Thank for any help.

Comment: How about [iterating your child nodes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:) and judge whether they're located in the region?

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you create a CGRect and iterate over the nodes and check if the node's position is in the rect using [CGRectContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint).